# Vim how to add second argument to the buffer list (alternate file)?

Tags: vim, buffer, neovim

I frequently open two files at a time in (neo)vim

`nvim file1.py file2.py`

And I want to either put them side by side with `:vsplit#` (which I have remapped to a single keystroke) or to quickly switch from one to the other with `<C-6>`. Unfortunately, those commands only switch from the current to the alternate file. By default, the second file is in the argument list but is not actually opened and is not the alternate file. I can open the other file with `:bnext` or whatever and then an alternate file gets set and everything works as expected.

It's a small thing, but it seems to come up all the time in my workflow.

Is there a setting or config that can put all files in the argument list into the buffer list and populate the alternate file variable?

Answer (score 5):

You can set the alternate file manually using `@#`. So, for example, to set the alternate file to the 2nd buffer I can do:

```
:let @#=2
```

To run this command on startup you can do:

```
vim -c 'let @#=2' file1 file2
```

To do this automatically on startup you can add this to your `.vimrc`:

```
function! MyFunc()
    if len(@#) == 0 && bufnr("$") > 1
        let @#=2
    endif
endfunction

autocmd VimEnter * call MyFunc()
```

The function will first ensure that an alternate file is not already present then it will ensure that there is another buffer to set. After that, it will then set the alternate file to the second buffer. Using `automcd VimEnter` we then call the function and it now will automatically run when starting Vim.